# SerenityRest Filter Response Body

Tags: java, rest, response

I am trying to return the value "Welcome!" where the object contains "name" key that equals to "Subject". The response body data is as follows:

```
"payload": {
    "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
    "headers": [
       {
            "name": "Mime-Version",
            "value": "1.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Subject",
            "value": "Welcome!"
        },
        {
            "name": "To",
            "value": "Jane Doe <xyz@xyz.com>"
        },
        {
            "name": "Message-ID",
            "value": "<123456.abc.com>"
        }
```

The following snippet will return the first encountered "value": "1.0", but i need to get the value where name = "Subject". How can i filter the results and check for a matching string?

```
Response response = SerenityRest.rest()
   .contentType("application/json")
   .get("URL")
response.then().statusCode(200);
String subject = response.jsonPath().getString("payload.headers.value");
```

The value "Welcome" is not static but "name": "Subject" will never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question, if you are looking for a jsonpath filter to get the value associate with the field `"name": "Subject"`, this should should normally works:

```
"payload.headers[?(@.name=='Subject')].value"
```

But I take a look at [json-path rest-assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/usage#json-using-jsonpath) which is the library used by Serenity rest to perform json-path operation, and that library does not use standard json-path synthax but a synthax based on groovy lambda to perform advanced search. So this should work:

```
"headers.find{ it.name == 'Subject' }.value"
```

I test with a complete example:

```
JsonPath.from("{\"payload\": {\n" +
                "    \"mimeType\": \"multipart/alternative\",\n" +
                "    \"headers\": [\n" +
                "       {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"Mime-Version\",\n" +
                "            \"value\": \"1.0\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"Subject\",\n" +
                "            \"value\": \"Welcome!\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"To\",\n" +
                "            \"value\": \"Jane Doe <xyz@xyz.com>\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"Message-ID\",\n" +
                "            \"value\": \"<123456.abc.com>\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}}")
    .getString("headers.find{ it.name == 'Subject' }.value");
// returns "Welcome!"
```

This blog helps me to understand synthax change: 
[What's new in REST Assured 1.8?](https://blog.jayway.com/2013/04/12/whats-new-in-rest-assured-1-8/)

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thank you!